# How to initialize SDK and auto-log installs only for production env

Tags: expo, react-native-fbsdk-next

It seems to initialize SDK automatically on Android by default, but I don't wanna initialize SDK and send any events from development build.
So what I tried is, setting the `isAutoInitEnabled`  false in `app.json` and then do it in `index.js`. but it seems like not working as expected.
I'd appreciate if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong and how to do that.
Thanks!!

app.json

```json
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": "xxx",
          "clientToken": "xxx",
          "displayName": "xxx",
          "scheme": "xxx",
          "advertiserIDCollectionEnabled": true,
          "autoLogAppEventsEnabled": true,
          "isAutoInitEnabled": false,
        }
      ]
```

index.js

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { Settings as FB_SDK } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';
import { isDev } from '@config/env';
import App from './App';

if (!isDev) {
  FB_SDK.initializeSDK();
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Comment: it seems like Android not working with this configuration...If anyone knows how to do that, please let me know